# Curl throw exceptions in Laravel 4

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4

I'm trying to take info from site with curl. Using `file_get_contents()` isn't an option because is disabled on the server. So current source is this

```
class API
{
   function get_curl_content($url) {
       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       $result = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close($curl);
       return $result;
   }

   const CACHE_KEY = 'rate';

   public static function getRate() {
       if (Cache::has(self::CACHE_KEY)) {
           return Cache::get(self::CACHE_KEY);
       }

       $oneHourTimestamp = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1);
       $tenMinutesTimestamp = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);

       $result = $this->get_curl_content('https://example.com/');
       $rates = json_decode($result, TRUE);
       if (!$rates) {
          Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, '-', $tenMinutesTimestamp);
          return '-';
       }

       $Rate = @$rates['1']['2'];
       if (!$Rate) {
          Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, '-', $tenMinutesTimestamp);
          return '-';
       }

       Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, $Rate, $oneHourTimestamp);
       return $Rate;
    }
 }
```

When I execute this I got error's in laravel.log

```
roduction.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\PlainDisplayer::display() must be an instance of  Exception, instance of Error given, called in    /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php on line 280 and defined in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/PlainDisplayer.php:15
```

What is the problem here?

Update:

```
<?php

function get_curl_content($url) {
       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       $result = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close($curl);
       return $result;
}



$urldata = get_curl_content('https://example.com/');

echo $urldata;
```

I put only this in separated file and everything is showed perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked if there is another message in the Apache error log?

Comment: It is only this error..

Comment: Try to run your **curl** code outside of Laravel and see if it works there.

Comment: I've got ` Using $this when not in object context in` here `$result = $this->get_curl_content('https://example.com/');`

Comment: You're outside of the class. Just try to paste all the code from the **get_curl_content()** method into a separate file and run it.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is in your **getRate()** method. Try to comment all the lines there except the first ones and see if throws an error. If it doesn't uncomment some more code and find out which part of the code throws the error.

Comment: I don't understand what to comment since I use all.

Comment: I understand, but comment everything except the first if block and see if it throws and error then. If it doesn't uncomment the next 2 lines, check again, uncomment some more and so on. This way you'll figure out when the exception is thrown.

Comment: I leaved only `$urldata = get_curl_content('https://example.com/');         $rates = json_decode($urldata, TRUE);` I i've got `'Call to undefined function get_curl_content()'` is this because I call this in another function or?

Comment: Or I must move `get_curl_content();` outside whole class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113337/discussion-between-thefallen-and-stan).